# PL/SQL: Expression is of wrong type, assigning a cursor data to a VARRAY

Tags: sql, arrays, plsql, types, database-cursor

I'm trying to load some data that I query from a cursor to a simple VARRAY of VARCHAR2, but I'm getting a compiling error, PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type, here's my code:

```
TYPE V_REG_SANITARIO IS VARRAY (10) OF REGISTROS_SANITARIOS.NUM_REG_SAN%TYPE;  

TYPE reg_info_exp_art IS RECORD ( 
...
t_fabricante_reg_sanitario  V_REG_SANITARIO,  
...);

TYPE t_reg_info_exp_art IS TABLE OF reg_info_exp_art
  INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;


PROCEDURE p_sic_obtener_info_art (
  ...
  p_tabla           IN OUT    t_reg_info_exp_art,
  ...
)

cursor c1 (P_PROVR_GEN provr_trabajo.cod_provr_gen%TYPE, P_PROVR_TRA provr_trabajo.cod_provr_trabajo%TYPE)
IS Select rs.num_reg_san as reg_sanitario
         from registros_sanitarios rs
        where rs.cod_provr_trabajo = P_PROVR_TRA
          and rs.cod_provr_gen = P_PROVR_GEN;
v_cont            number :=1;

...
FOR reg1 IN ... LOOP
  for i in c1(v_provr_gen, v_provr_trabajo) loop              
      p_Tabla(v_cont).t_fabricante_reg_sanitario(i) := i.reg_sanitario;  --HERE I GET MY ERROR
  end loop;
...
end loop;
```

Comment: Within your cursor loop, `t_fabricante_reg_sanitario(i)` expects `i` to be a binary integer, but it's a record with an attribute named `reg_sanitario`.

Comment: Maybe it should be `t_fabricante_reg_sanitario(reg1)`, as `reg1` is the loop index?